# Pi4 MCP3008 - SPI port setup failed, no SPI available

Tags: pi-4, spi, java, pi4j

I am trying to use a joystick with a MCP3008 in the middle (Connected to GPIO8 - SPI CS0) but I get following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: SPI port setup failed, no SPI
> available.
> at com.pi4j.io.spi.impl.SpiDeviceImpl.(SpiDeviceImpl.java:66)
> at com.pi4j.io.spi.SpiFactory.getInstance(SpiFactory.java:110)
> at PushButtonTest.main(PushButtonTest.java:54)
> ... 8 more

It's thrown by following code:

```
spi = SpiFactory.getInstance(SpiChannel.CS0,
            SpiDevice.DEFAULT_SPI_SPEED, // default spi speed 1 MHz
            SpiDevice.DEFAULT_SPI_MODE); // default spi mode 0
```

SPI is enabled as:

```
 $ lsmod | grep spi_
spi_bcm2835            24576  0

 $ ls /dev/spi*
/dev/spidev1.0  /dev/spidev1.1  /dev/spidev1.2
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Is the SPI device present? Please `EDIT` your question and include the output of `ls /dev/spi*`

Comment: @joan it gives me "ls: cannot access '/dev/spi*': No such file or directory"

Comment: Did you enable SPI with raspi-config? https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/08/enabling-the-spi-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: You need to ask the Pi4J folks for support. Try running a python SPI (spidev) program and you'll find it works just fine.